# Correct encoding-type on form in CURL-command when submitting to django-rest-api

Tags: curl, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework and have a model, that has as only field a file-field.
I created a serializer and views and everything else. Everything seems to work correct, because when using the web-api, I am able to upload a file without problems. But when trying to use CURL to test it, I always get

> {"data": ["No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form."]}%

I've been trying a lot of commands, but all of them end up in this error message. The commands I tried where:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -u stefan:stefan -F "data=/home/erdi/Videos/search4.webm" http://127.0.0.1:8000/restapp/sportvideosupload/

curl -X POST -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u "stefan:stefan" --data-binary '{"data":"/home/erdi/Videos/search2.webm"}' 127.0.0.1:8000/restapp/sportvideosupload/

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -u stefan:stefan -F "data=/home/erdi/Videos/search2.webm;type=video/webm" http://127.0.0.1:8000/restapp/sportvideosupload/
```

As I am a beginner in using restful apis, I hope, that maybe one of you has suggestions, in what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, I could answer the question by myself. The problem was a missing @ - character for local files. A working command for me is: curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u stefan:stefan -F "data=@/home/erdi/Videos/search4.webm" http://127.0.0.1:8000/restapp/sportvideosupload/